# VBA Excel - Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to figure out why I get the above error when I run this code.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't?  The code sits in a sheet rather than a module and I suspect that may be the problem, but the same piece of code runs fine in another sheet in the workbook.

Please can someone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks.

```
Sub DeleteRow()

On Error GoTo error_handler

Dim Button As Shape
Dim CellinRowtoDelete As Range

'Run sub routine
ClearSearchandFilter

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Determine which row needs to be deleted
ButtonLocation = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address
Range(ButtonLocation).Select

'Select and delete buttons before deleting the row
Set CellinRowtoDelete = ActiveCell
For Each Button In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Button.TopLeftCell.Address), CellinRowtoDelete) Is Nothing Then
        Button.Select
        Button.Delete
    End If
Next

'Delete the row
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

'Re-format cells in row 8 with a red box incase the bottom has been removed by deleting row 9
Range("W8:AM8").Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
Range("X5").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub
Error_handler:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when it throws the error? Also, this definitely should sit inside a module.

Comment: It doesn't highlight a line.  It just throws up an error.  I put the error handler in to be able to see what the error is but it does not say where in the code?

Comment: I think it is the if not application.intersect(..... line that throws the error

Comment: First off, the error handler's name doesn't match. `On Error GoTo error_handler` on top and `Error_handler` on bottom. Notice the first letter. Fix that one. If it still throws the error, remove it and run again. Let us know if it highlights on this.

Comment: The code runs on the click of a button.  The whole point of the code is to delete the line the button sits on but first it has to delete an buttons on the line otherwise they just build up.

Comment: Fixed typo but still get error.  Took error handler out and got a 400 error but no highlight of a line.

Comment: Okay, posting code in a moment...

Answer (score 0):

First off, you really should not use `.Select`, `.Activate`, or anything `Active`, really. It will mess up your code more than it will help it (except for *very* few instances).

Second, instead of checking the intersection with a cell, try checking the intersection against the whole row. Since you're deleting all of the buttons in that row anyway (if I got you correctly), this will be more exact as even an off-cell-center will be deleted. This might sound confusing but bear with me.

Kindly try the following code.

```
Sub DeleteRow()

    Dim Button As Shape
    Dim RowToDelete As Range

    'Run sub routine
    ClearSearchandFilter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Determine which row needs to be deleted
    ButtonLocation = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address
    Set RowToDelete = Range(ButtonLocation).EntireRow

    'Select and delete buttons before deleting the row
    For Each Button In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Button.TopLeftCell.Address), RowToDelete) Is Nothing Then
            Button.Delete
        End If
    Next

    'Delete the row
    RowToDelete.Delete

    'Re-format cells in row 8 with a red box incase the bottom has been removed by deleting row 9
    With Range("W8:AM8").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Let us know what's the result.

Comment: Sorry, still same issue.  If I step it through it will sometimes work but clicking the button throws the error?

Comment: Are you using an ActiveX button?

Comment: No, a form button on a sheet.

Comment: Copy and paste the above into a standard module. Recreate the button and when prompted to assign to a macro, assign it to this one. Then run it again.

Comment: Still no joy.  The issue seems to be to do with the button numbers.

Comment: There are a lot of buttons on the sheet (1 or 2 per line) and sometimes it does not like the button numbers and their order.